# Change this short assembler code so it works just without register-indexed

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

Task from an old exam (I can provide source if you don't believe me):

Change the following assembler code without using register-indexed addressing. Do not use more than `4` instructions.

```
mov eax, [ebx+8]
add eax, 1
add ebx, 8
mov [ebx], eax
```

I have changed that to:

```
mov eax, [ebx]
add eax, 9
add ebx, 8
mov [ebx], eax
```

I cannot imagine it's done that easily that's why I'm not sure :D

if that's right what I did, an alternative would be:

```
mov eax, [ebx]
add eax, 1
add ebx, 16
mov [ebx], eax
```

Or is it now completely wrong? Thank you very much everyone!

**Edit: Corrected version:**

```
mov eax, [ebx]
add [ebx], 9
add ebx, 8
mov [ebx], eax
```

Now?

Comment: It's completely wrong. You're reading from the wrong location in your first solution, and reading and writing the wrong locations in the second location.

Comment: Oh that hurts, alright thank you for fast comment! Let me try to correct it.

Comment: if ebx=1000, then the `mov eax,[ebx+8]` loads eax with 32b value from address 1008. Your `mov eax,[ebx]` would load eax with 32b value from address 1000. If I understand that wording of task correctly, then it's in some sense less to change, than you did in your first try.

Comment: Edited version still works on wrong memory spot. Imagine memory as street with small houses, each has house number from 0 to N, that's address. And inside the house lives some number. With that ebx=1000 example you are by `[ebx+8]` taking out number from house 1008. With `[ebx]` you take out number from completely different house, at address 1000.

Comment: And once you get familiar with that, bend that mental image a bit more, because by `mov eax,[ebx+8]` you are actually taking out four 8 bit numbers from houses 1008, 1009, 1010 and 1011, concatenating them together in a way that number from house 1011 is the highest significant byte (bits 31..24) and house 1008 provided the least significant byte (bits 7..0).

Comment: I better go sleep now it's very late and I shouldn't have asked at a time like that because it's just more confusing. I will try to solve and understand this tomorrow it will be better I believe. Thank you a lot by the way, you helped me very much today!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, none of the addressing modes in the original use an index register.  `[ebx+8]` can (and will) use EBX as a base register, not an index register, because it can do that without a SIB byte in the machine-code encoding.  So the addressing mode is base+disp8, so the encoding of the ModRM byte would be (in binary)

- Mod=01  (base+disp8)
- R/M = 011  (EBX)
- REG = 000 (EAX as the register destination)

So the ModRM byte would be 0x43, as per *Table 2-2. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte*, in Intel's instruction-set reference manual (Volume 2).  (See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to the PDFs).

If there was a scale factor on EBX (like `[ebx*2 + 8]`), it would have to use the disp32 + index addressing mode.  (See also [x86 addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058400/224132)).

---

Presumably you actually mean you can't use a displacement in your addressing mode.

In that case, **the first instruction can't be the load, because you have to calculate the address in a register first**.  The question makes it easy for you, by later calculating the same `ebx+8` value that you need as an address, using an ADD instruction.  So you can just reorder, instead of having to modify EBX twice.

```
add ebx, 8
mov eax, [ebx]
add eax, 1
mov [ebx], eax
```

Or slower but fewer instructions:

```
add   ebx, 8
add   dword [ebx], 1     ; read-modify-write
mov   eax, [ebx]         ; and then reload
```

---

x86 has many weird and wonderful instructions, including [XADD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XADD.html).  You could even do this:

```
                           ; LEA ebx, [ebx+8]  might count as breaking the rules, even though it's not a load.
sub   ebx, -8              ; use a different instruction just for variety.  
mov   eax, 1
xadd  dword [ebx], eax     ; read-modify-write, leaving the old value in eax
inc   eax                  ; do the same add again, so the register matches what xadd put into memory.
```

**But don't do this.  XADD is slower** than normal simple instructions.  It's main purpose is multi-threaded synchronization.  C++11's [std::atomic::fetch_add](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add) is the same operation that XADD implements, so fetch_add() can compile efficiently on x86 to a `lock xadd`.